# Evaluating limits of nested functions

Tags: calculus, limits

I am interested in how we can approximate limits of functions of the form:
$$g(x)=f\circ f\circ f\circ f\circ f\circ ...(x)$$
If we take the function $f(x)=\sin(x)$ for example we get:
$$g(x)=\sin(\sin(\sin(\sin...(x))))$$
as far as I can tell, for $x\in\Re$ the function $g(x)\to0$

How could I prove this?

My only thought so far is that $|\sin(x)|\le1$ and so $|\sin(\sin(x))|\le\sin(1)<1$
Can I continue this to prove the limit?

Comment: For general $f$, you might want to look at theorems on fixed point iteration. There is [one on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_iteration#Properties) that requires $f$ to be Lipschitz with $L < 1$, which does not apply here since the sine function has Lipschitz constant $L = 1$, but maybe you can modify the argument.

Comment: The limit does not go to zero if $x = (n+1/2)\pi$.  But otherwise, it should.

Comment: Start from $\frac{1}{\sin^2(x)} - \frac{1}{x^2} = \frac13  + \frac{x^2}{15} + \frac{2x^4}{189} + \cdots$, one can show
$$\sin^{\circ n}(x) = \sqrt{\frac{3}{n}}\left\{ 1 - \frac{3}{10} \frac{\log n}{n} + \cdots \right\}$$
For more terms and a full derivation, see $\S 8.6$ 'Iteration of the sine function' in N.G. de Brujin's book [Asymptotic methods in analysis](https://www.amazon.com/Asymptotic-Methods-Analysis-Dover-Mathematics/dp/0486642216).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

W.l.G. we can assume $x\in[-1,1]$, 
if $x=0$, the case is easy;

if $x\in(0,1]$, then $\sin x <x$,
this implies the sequence{ $x_n=\sin x_{n-1}\}$
is monotone decreasing.
Monotone bounded principle implies this sequence has limit 
$x_0$ and satisfies 
  $$x_0=\sin x_0.$$ 
This equation has unique solution $x_0=0.$

If $x\in[-1,0)$, you can consider as the same way and get the same limit!

Comment: I don't think $0 < f'(x) < \cos( 1)$ holds. Rather it is $\cos (1) < f'(x) \le \cos( 0) = 1$ for $x \in (-1, 1)$.

Comment: Yes,you are right!@ angryavian

Comment: But this means that you cannot directly use the fixed point theorem from Wikipedia since the Lipschitz constant is not strictly less than $1$. This is the content of my comment on the original question.

Comment: you are right @angryavian, and I change the method.

Answer (score 1):

Without fixed point theory: let be $x_{n+1} = \sin(x_n)$, $x_0\in\Bbb R$. Wlog we can suppose $0\le x_0\le 1$ (why?). As for all $x$ in this interval $0\le\sin(x)\le x$, our sequence is decreasing and bounded, so convergent. And the limit only can be...